# mat-slide-toggle change true / false in Firestore automatically

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material2

Can I change the true / false status of a mat-slide-toggle automatically in relation to a certain time? I'm working with Firestore.

I wish that when it is `true`, after 24 hours it will automatically change to `false`. Is this possible?

What I try is to give access to a content for a certain time.

My code at the moment updates well but manually:

component.html

```
<mat-slide-toggle #toggle [ngModel]="aviso.publicado" (ngModelChange)="actualizarPublicado(aviso.id, aviso, $event)">
  <span *ngIf="!aviso.publicado" class="text-muted">No publicado</span>
  <span *ngIf="aviso.publicado" class="text-primary">Publicado</span>
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

component.ts

```
actualizarPublicado(key, obj, e){
  this.fs.updatePublicado(key, e);
}
```

service.ts

```
updatePublicado(key, publicado){
  this.afs.doc('avisos/' + key).update({publicado});
}
```

Comment: this spanglish code is not serious, updatePublicado! O.o, I'm not fan of programming in spanish but if you have to I think is better to write all in spanish, not a strange mix

Comment: @Umpa jajaja thank you for your comment, I thought it was something more important.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using setInterval function?

```
toggleValue = false;
interval : any;

ngOnInit(){
    this.set24HourInterval();
}

set24HourInterval(){
    this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
        this.toggleValue = !this.toggleValue;
        this.fs.updatePublicado(this.aviso.id, this.toggleValue);
    },24*60*60*1000);
}
```

And if you want it to stop iterating according to a condition, you can simply use

```
this.clearInterval(this.interval);
```

inside that function.

UPDATED:

```
  actualizarPublicado() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.avisos.subscribe((avisos) => {
        avisos.forEach((aviso) => {
          aviso.publicado = !aviso.publicado;
          this.fs.updatePublicado(aviso.id, aviso.publicado);
        });
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying, for now I get an error ts in `aviso`
[ts] The property "aviso" does not exist in the type "MyComponent".  I tried to define it but then I get an error in the ID

Comment: Where are you getting aviso object in (ngModelChange)="actualizarPublicado(aviso.id, aviso, $event)" ? The same needs to be used here.

Comment: I made a stackblitz so you can see the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-slide-toggle-true-false

Comment: avisos is an array. Do you want the interval to be called for all the objects of avisos array? I thought aviso object is an independent variable. But now I have seen your complete html, so it is just an iteration object.

Comment: Yes is an array. Yes, is possible?

Comment: Okay, let me try.

Comment: https://mat-slide-toggle-true-false-qf7m2o.stackblitz.io This is what I have tried.

Comment: I can not see the changes, I think you have to save this stackblitz apart or give it "fork"

Comment: I have updated it. Check this one : https://mat-slide-toggle-true-false-y5mgft.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thanks I will analyze it, at the moment I see that it does not update the field in Firestore. I will try to see what happens.

Comment: This one is updated :https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-slide-toggle-true-false-vskdul

Comment: Yes, I see it. I can see that when it is in `true` after 5 seconds it does not go back to false and it also does not update the `publicado` field

Comment: I was an approach for setting an interval. Rest is all up to your logic, how you use it. That's all I can help :)

Comment: Okay, I really appreciate the help